# Why does Illustrator add invisible layers on top of files when transfered from one computer to the other?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

Every time I take a file from work and open it at home, there appear all these invisible boxes that group everything together. Sometimes there are multiple invisible suck boxes over the same part of the same image. Why does the program do this and how can I make it stop? It adds an extra ten minutes to open each file where i have to find the invisible things and delete them so i can access the vectors below.

Comment: Are you using the absolute same AI version in both workplaces?

Comment: no, actually i am using an older version at home

Answer (score 3):

Older AI software (lets say CS6) will generally open newer AI files (CC) inside a clipping mask, which is what you're seeing. Need to run the same AI version on both machines basicly.

Comment: well thanks for the heads up but adobe will never get me to pay for a subscription service for a program that hasn't improved in 10 years

Comment: That's your decision i guess. I'm paying for AI and don't really need it improved, i just need it to work, which it does.